# Is there MSSQL Server Driver for PHP on a 64-bit environment?

Tags: php, pdo

Is there a driver for MSSQL Server for PHP (64-bit)?

I have Apache 2.4 (64-bit) environment installed. Also PHP 5.5.12 (64-bit)

I have search for MSSQL Server driver "on the net" for php 64-bit but I found nothing. All I can find is a 32-bit. Also, all the articles that I found were old and nothing recent.

I tried to install the 32-bit driver but I get a warning when executing `C:\php>php -m`
This is the warning

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
```

I downloaded the MSSQL Server Driver from [Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)
If there a MSSQL Server driver available for PHP 64-bit environment?
If not is there a workaround beside having to go back to 32-bit PHP environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180984/installing-sql-server-driver-for-php

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue as well.  What I have found is that you need to make sure that the extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll area of your php.ini file is only uncommented on the Apache location of php.ini.

For example:

if you have *C:\Webserver\bin\apache\bin\php.ini*, you probably have a *C:\Webserver\bin\php\php.ini* as well.  Make sure your extension referrences are ONLY in the ...\apache\bin\php.ini.

It took me **3 hours** to realize there were 2 different php.ini files and that the error was throwing because I had the extension initialized in the wrong php.ini file yet it was still looking there for some reason. I hope this helped.

Comment: It's not directly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating to php 7 ?

The x64 builds of PHP 5 for Windows are experimental, and do not provide 64-bit integer or large file support. Therefore I doubt MS will release a php5 version of the driver especially since the one for php 7 has been out for a few months now.

This MSSQL driver was release in July of 2016

Download the "SQLSRV40.EXE" from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

The executable is a self-extractor, unpack where you want.
You even get the PDO for the same price.
Here are the files in the package

- PHP Drivers License Terms.rtf
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
- php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
- php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
- php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
- php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
- release.txt
- SQLSRV_Readme.htm
- SQLSRV_ThirdPartyNotices.rtf

Tested with php 7.0, 7.1, 7.2

Comment: I'm trying to set this up, but I'm stuck on loading the SQL server extension in PHP.ini
I have added this line 
extension="C:\PHP7\ext\php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll"
but when I run php it throws this error:
 Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP7\ext\php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll' (tried: C:\PHP7\ext\php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:/PHP7/ext\php_C:\PHP7\ext\php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0